# MySQL #1064 syntax error when creating a table

Tags: mysql

I have this table, which worked perfectly fine in sql developer, but when I wanted to import it to the MySQL database this is what happend:

```
CREATE TABLE zem(
ID_zem INTEGER,
nazov VARCHAR2(30), 
kontinent VARCHAR2(30),

CONSTRAINT pk_zem PRIMARY KEY (ID_zem)
);
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that     corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'VARCHAR2(30),  kontinent VARCHAR2(30),
>
> CONSTRAINT pk_zem PRIMARY KEY (ID_zem' at line 3

Comment: Please don't tag databases you're not using. I've removed `oracle` tag.

Comment: Well, you cannot use Oracle syntax with MySQL, no matter what client program you use.

Comment: ok then, is there any way I can import my databases with Oracle syntax? Or I need to rewrite them?

Comment: varchar2 is oracle syntax...

Comment: varchar2 is not supported by mysql use varchar instead of it...

Comment: No, you obviously cannot. How is MySQL going to know about other engines' data types? What about features that Oracle support and MySQL doesn't, such as check constraints or sequences?

Answer (score 2):

change

```
VARCHAR2
```

to

```
VARCHAR
```

there is no `varchar2` in mysql

Answer (score 2):

There is [How to Create tables in MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html), for integer use value like INTEGER(11) -> but is not necessary and MySql does not have data type VARCHAR2, only **VARCHAR**

```
CREATE TABLE zem (
ID_zem INTEGER(11) not null,
nazov VARCHAR(30), 
kontinent VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY (ID_zem)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: What is ENGINE=INNODB?

Comment: Storage engine of MySql DB for your data, [Storage Engines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-engines.html)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
CREATE TABLE zem(
ID_zem INT,
nazov VARCHAR(30), 
kontinent VARCHAR(30),
CONSTRAINT pk_zem PRIMARY KEY (ID_zem)
);
```